# Is it possible to loop 1, 4, 7, 10 sequence directly in ngFor from an array?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to loop 1, 4, 7, 10  sequence directly in ngFor from an array?

I tried in ts like regular for loop with i+=3. But need 1,4,7,10 pattern directly in ngFor without a loop in ts file.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do inside this `ngFor`? It's more akin to a for each loop than a standard for loop, so there isn't a step/increment expression. The likely answer is to perform some kind of transform on the data you're iterating over in the TS file, but it'll be clearer with more info.

Answer (score 1):

ngFor is very similar to the .ForEach() method.

You could use an ngIf statement to check if the index is divisible by 3 before displaying it.

```
    <div *ngFor="item in itemlist, let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i % 3 === 1">
{{item}}
    </div>
    </div>
```

You could also check the item directly instead of the index. Depending on how your array of numbers is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your case, You just need to put this condition
i % 3 === 1 which allows only 1, 4, 7, and 10;

```
  <div *ngFor="item of items, let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i % 3 === 1">
       {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
```